# Как лучше всего разделять объект stream между разными частями библиотечного кода?

Tags: c++, проектирование

Вопрос: как разделять объект класса по работе со стримом (поток байтов) между разными частями библиотечного кода? Во всех этих частях кода нужно иметь возможность изменять стрим.

Такая же проблема о разделении стрима по библиотечному коду встречается и при разработке библиотеки логирования подобной log4j архитектуре. Когда имеется только один файл, но при этом различные уровни, к примеру такой: 'com.supersite.componentname.applicationname'.

**UPD**
Пишу библиотеку по работе с PE-форматом. Для работы как с 32- так и 64-битными образами. Образы бывают файловые (на диске, флешке) и виртуальные (процесс запущен на выполнение).

Мне надо:

- получать доступ по чтению к уже существующей в образе информации;
- добавлять новую информацию в образ;
- удалять\изменять существующую информацию из\в образа\зе.

Я не хочу привязываться к файлу или памяти и поэтому решил работать с интерфейсом стрима. В текущий момент времени сделано так:

```
template<typename arch_type>
class Image {
public:
  Image(std::iostream& stream_) : stream(stream_) {}

  std::iostream& getStream() const { return stream; }

  const IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY& getExportDirHeader() const { return exportDirHeader; }
  const ImportDescriptors_t& getImportDirHeaders() const { return importDirDescriptors; }

private:
  std::iostream& stream;
  IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exportDir;
  ImportDescriptors_t importDirDescriptors;
}
```

Это минимальный интерфейс класса, есть еще с десяток методов. Также есть другие методы по работе с экспортом, импортом, баундом и др. концепциями, которые возвращают подробности, т.е. список экспортируемых\импортируемых элементов их rva, названия и др. полезные детали.

Пока все выглядит так:

```
using namespace PE;
using namespace std;

ifstream stream("calc.exe");
Image<arch32> image(stream);

Export::Details exportDetails;
fillDetails(image, &exportDetails);

Import::Details importDetails;
fillDetails(image, &importDetails);
```

Другими словами:

1. Перед использованием класса Image создаю стрим и передаю в объект Image.
2. Каждая функция, которой что-то надо сделать с Image, к примеру вытащить информацию об TLS-калбаках, она берет объект Image, а в своем коде, когда надо использовать стрим, она вызывает getStream().

Получается, что у меня происходит "растекание стрима" по всему библиотечному коду!

Мне это "растекание стрима" очень и очень мешает реализовать фичу.

Comment: прямой доступ к стриму должен иметь только один класс. Всем остальным классам этот доступ предоставляется через класс-собственник стрима. Другие классы не должны закладываться на внутреннее строение стрима.

Поэтому, сделайте обертку вокруг стрима, и ее передавайте как параметр в нужные функции, классы. Если в каком то классе будет слишком много работы с стримом через обертку - выносите этот кусок в обертку.

Comment: @kovadim

1. Оно понятно, что объект класса должен быть один. Вопрос, как все это организовать? Можно один класс StreamManager на базе паттерна Singleton, который будет создавать стримы и возвращать streamid и иметь методы Stream& getStream(streamid). А можно создать метод стрима и положить его в boost::shared_ptr . Вопрос как раз в том, что лучше? Какую стратегию предпочесть?

2. А почему Вы не хотите писать в виде ответов? Ведь не удобно в случае чего Ваш комментарий помечать как ответ.

Comment: 1. По всякому может быть. В зависимости от решаемой задачи. Так как задача неизвестна мне, то и решение предложить не могу.

2. А какой же это ответ - это так, комментарий.

Comment: 1. ОК. Допишу пост в виде UPD. Дописал. Если что-то непонятно, то спрашивайте уточняющие вопросы

Comment: Класс Image должен уметь делать низкоуровневые функции по отношению к стриму -  "прочитать заголовок", "прочитать строку", и на самый конец - "прочитать n байт по смещению m". Теперь, всем дополнительным функциям/классам, которые изучают/модифицируют структуру, уже не нужно обращаться к стриму - у них есть "среднеуровненвые" функции. Но похоже, ее все равно придется "размазывать между классами". Но в этот класс можно встроить счетчик ссылок (посредством умного указателя) и будет заметно легче.

Comment: @KoVadim:

1.
Ваш вариант мне несколько не понятен. Почему Вы предлагаете добавить методы readString(), readDataAt(uint8_t * dest, int pos, int len)? Чем же будет отличаться от интерфейса Stream? Я думал об этом варианте, но я не хотел бы, чтобы пользовательский код видел.

2.
Я думаю над следующим: ввести класс StreamManager с методами "streamid open(filename)", "Stream getStream(streamid id)", "close(streamid)" и сделать его синглтоном. А в Image передавать только streamid и заменить getStream() на getStreamId(). Это позволит в случае изменений менять только и только реализацию StreamManage

Comment: синглтон точно не нужен.

Я предлагал отвязаться от стандартного стрима. Если где то в нутрях кода нужно будет сделать что то нестандартное (к примеру, прочитать адрес, потом по этому адресу прочитать другой адрес, а потом по нему прочитать строку), то это можно вынести в этот класс.

Раз у Вас уже есть идея - пишите ее. отлаживайте. Пока не попробуете, не сможете сделать лучше. А потом попробуете порефакторить.

Comment: @KoVadim: 

3. Вы сейчас уже пытаетесь ответить и помочь мне. Это уже не просто комментарии! ;) Сейчас пришлось удалить свой прошлый комментарий, чтобы этот добавить :)

4. Да, мантру "пока не попробуешь" знаю. Только вот уже раз 5 рефакторю и каждый раз не нравится. Хочется как-то сделать на совесть один раз и чтобы худо-бедно всегда нравилось. :)

Comment: По-моему, все очень элегантно. Есть данные - стрим. Обернуты они во что-то или голые, в зависимости от необходимости вариантов использования- не важно, понадобится обернуть- можно будет отрефакторить. 
Есть контролы, которые, собственно, и реализуют варианты использования данных.
Если есть проблема параллельного доступа, стоит сделать обертку для объектов ядра для этой цели. И надо определиться с владением данными: раздавайте по потокам shared_ptr/weak_ptr в зависимости от того, кто управляет уременем жизни стрима.
Собственно, как сделано - уже вполне приятно, надо только эти детали докрутить

Comment: Оцените, сколько и каких вариантов изменения/снятия состояния этих данных вам надо, это будет тот самый объем кода, по которому эти данные будут размазаны, и меньше невозможно, без уменьшения количества этих вариантов использования.
И даже если Вы обернете данные во что-то, что возьмет на себя, например, низкоуровневое взаимодействие, как предложил KoVadim, все равно каждый вариант использования данных будет вынужден иметь то, что ему надо использовать, что и отметил KoVadim :)